# Why do we use format identifier python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginner and learning Python. My question is python can read a variable in a string without format identifier, then why has format identifiers been provided for?

Ex:

```
carPoolTotal = 4
print "We have total", carPoolTotal, "people in carpooling."

print "We have total %d people in carpooling." % carPoolTotal
```

Both works the same thing, then why exactly is identifier introduced in Python?

Comment: The second gives you more formatting options

Comment: @cricket_007: Nice. Thanks for your time and thanks for correcting my editing blunder.

Comment: The thing with commas only works with `print`.

Comment: @Rawing: All right! I guess I have not reached that far in Python to know about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format identifiers help if you want to provide non-default formatting for your values. For example, you might want to format a long decimal as a decimal with a maximum of two decimal places.